# Fifa 23 PC EA app can no longer sync saves to the cloud

Tags: fifa-23

In the last couple of days, whenever I play Fifa, I get a message from the EA app after quitting that it cannot send the 100 KB save file to the cloud.

After I try to start again, I get a message that I only have a day old local save and if I want, I can use it but all my progress will be lost.

[image]

How can't EA manage to store KBs of data?
Maybe they should use Azure or AWS to store that huge amount?

What happens if I use my older local save? Will I lose every player, every match record that is played and not saved locally?